# iTextSharp: Copying a PDF outputs hidden text in resulting PDF

Tags: itext

We're using iTextSharp to create a copy of a page range of PDF files. This works just fine, however when copying PDF files that contain hidden text, this text is outputted to the result of the copy anyways.

This is the PDF copying logic:

```
using (var reader = new DisposablePdfReader(filePath))
{
    int pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
    Document doc = null;
    PdfCopy copy = null;
    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    doc = new Document();
    copy = new PdfCopy(doc, stream);

    doc.Open();

    foreach (int pageNumber in pages)
        if (pageNumber > 0 && pageNumber <= pageCount)
        {
            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber));
        }

    return new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray());
}
```

Any ideas as to how to make hidden text stay hidden, in the resulting copy? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A wild guess: you're copying the page streams but not the OCG dictionary?

Comment: Or is the text hidden by other means than OCGs? Or does hiding depend on execution of some JavaScript code?

Comment: The content of the PDFs themselves are out of our control, so I don't know how the text gets hidden. I don't believe our clients use JavaScript code in the PDFs they provide us, but I'll put it on my investigation list. Regarding to OCGs, I've looked through the API documentation, and are having a hard time finding references how to access or copy these settings. Any pointers for me to work on from? Thank you very much for your comments!

Comment: Please provide a sample PDF for inspection.

Comment: I'm sorry that I never came back on this one - It's not possible for me to provide the exact PDF, due to copyright issues. I can however see that the PDF that iTextSharp outputs has no layers at at all, whereas the original has plenty.